# Can I directly alter files located in a GlusterFS brick

Tags: glusterfs

On a storage node, GlusterFS bricks (the physical disks composing a GlusterFS volume) are typically mounted at a specific location. For example: `/export/glusterfs/<volume>/brick0/brick`.

However to use a GlusterFS volume, it must be mounted:

```
mount -t glusterfs gluster.example.com:/<volume> /mnt
```

Now I can change all the files in `/mnt` and GlusterFS will do its magic. However, we can also see the same files in `/export/glusterfs/<volume>/brick0/brick`.

Can the files in `/export/glusterfs/<volume>/brick0/brick` be changed without breaking GlusterFS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, technically you can modify files in the underling volume, but Gluster will **not** be notified about your changes, and therefore they may not be replicated to other Gluster nodes.

This is **very much not recommended**, and could mean that your servers end up with different underlying files, which can lead to unpredictable behaviour/data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Once I have several files copied directly to the brick, is there any way to make Gluster be aware about those new files?

Comment: The bricks should not be used directly. They are managed by GlusterFS. It is best to mount the Gluster volume and then copy the files.

Comment: Yes, I know. Just asking in case accidentally someone copy data directly to the brick.

Comment: @DaniloMussolini I had done this exact mistake without realizing I have mounted the brick path directly and not the glusterfs. I had to mount the glusterfs path, and touch each file (I used `chwon -R`) so that gluster gets the file change notifications, and the files appeared on other peers as well.